# How configure aspectj compilation in playframework 2.1.1

Tags: sbt, aspectj, spring-aop, playframework-2.1

I have added to plugins.sbt this declaration

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.0")
```

Now I would like to configure this plugin to compile my java controller classes using aspect library org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.1.4 as with aspectj-maven-plugin

I have set this configuration :

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.AspectjKeys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appDependencies = Seq(javaCore)

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        AspectjKeys.verbose in Aspectj := true,
        AspectjKeys.showWeaveInfo in Aspectj := true,
        AspectjKeys.inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses
    )

}
```

But it does fail.

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   aspectj:inputs from aspectj:inputs
```

I am really a newbie with the sbt thing.

The plugin github page : https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I make it works, thanks to sbt mailing list, cf. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/simple-build-tool/MUXyfKigC7w

and the playframework mailing list also, cf. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/RfJFEwVbUUk

It was not very hard in fact but something you can't see things.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.AspectjKeys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appDependencies = Seq(javaCore, filters)

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
            .settings(aspectjSettings: _*)
            .settings(
                    libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-aspects" % "3.1.4.RELEASE",
                    libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-aspects" % "3.1.4.RELEASE",
                    sourceLevel := "-1.7",
                    verbose in Aspectj := false,
                    showWeaveInfo in Aspectj := false,
                    inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses,
                    binaries in Aspectj <++= update map { report =>
                        report.matching(
                                moduleFilter(organization = "org.springframework", name = "spring-aspects")
                                || moduleFilter(organization = "org.springframework.security", name = "spring-security-aspects")
                        )
                    },
                    products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj,
                    products in Runtime <<= products in Compile
                )
}
```

Don't forget to add this in in plugins.sbt, with a new line separator between declaration

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.0")
```