# AspectJ loads but ignores class in Play Framework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework-2.0, aspectj

I'm having trouble getting my AspectJ aspect to work in the Play 2.2.2 framework. This seems to be a problem that also other people tried to solve (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780051/aspectj-in-play-framework-2-2-1-java)), but so far I was unsuccessful in finding an answer.
This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a play java application and I'm trying to build an @Trace annotation for method-enter and method-leave tracing. So basically, I want a method that is annotated with @Trace to log its name and input arguments and to log the result on exit. I thought AOP with AspectJ would be an elegant way to do that, in order to avoid having to clutter my code with log.debug(...) calls.

Here is the aspect that I came up with:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("@annotation(trace)")
    public void methodAnnotatedWithTrace(Trace trace) {}

    @Before("methodAnnotatedWithTrace(trace)")
    public void traceBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, Trace trace) {
        log.debug("Entering - {} ", joinPoint.getSignature());
    }

    @AfterReturning("methodAnnotatedWithTrace(trace)")
    public void traceAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Trace trace) {
        log.debug("Exiting - {}", joinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

I added the following dependencies in my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt"     % "1.8.1"
```

And I specified the following aop.xml:

```xml
<aspectj>

  <aspects>
    <aspect name="aspects.LoggingAspect"/>
  </aspects>

  <weaver options="-verbose -XnoInline -showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="aspects.*"/>
    <include within="controllers.*"/>
  </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

I also added the aspectj weaver to PLAY_OPTS:

```
set PLAY_OPTS=-javaagent:C:\\Users\\...\\play-2.2.2\\repository\\cache\\org.aspectj\\aspectjweaver\\jars\\aspectjweaver-1.8.1.jar
```

And I annotated my method with @Trace:

```java
@Trace
public Result doSomething(String msg) { ... }
```

As a result, I get the following output when running "play test":

```
[1@2a1ffa9f] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.1 built on Saturday Jun 21, 2014 at 00:07:06 GMT
[1@2a1ffa9f] info register classloader sbt.classpath.ClasspathUtilities$$anon$1@2a1ffa9f
[1@2a1ffa9f] info using configuration /C:/Users/Stephanie/Documents/projects/zeitgenossen/target/scala-2.10/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[1@2a1ffa9f] info register aspect aspects.LoggingAspect
```

That's all. I do not see the trace. It seems like the annotation is simply ignored.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does your annotation @Trace have runtime retention? If it doesn't then AspectJ would not see it in the class file when loadtime weaving.

Incidentally, `@annotation(trace)` is the very general form of annotation matching, which attempts to match annotations at any kind of joinpoint, not just methods. So if you read or write a field with the annotation on, or handle an exception whose type has that annotation - those would all be matched. And if you do call a method with the annotation on you would get the advice running twice, once for the method 'call' and once for the method 'execution'.  You should probably restrict the matching to the kinds of joinpoint you are interested in:

`execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(trace)`

Now I imagine you are only annotating methods but the digging around for annotations can be costly, so if you limit it to only looking at method execution joinpoints, you can speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andy! I will change the pointcut definition accordinly. 
btw: @Trace does have runtime retention in my case. The problem seems to be a different one in my case. But thanks anyway.